# Computing the order of a distribution

Tags: distribution-theory

I need to prove that the order of the distribution given by $$\langle T,\varphi\rangle=\int_\mathbb{R}(\varphi(t^{-2},\sin t)-\varphi(0,\sin t)) dt,$$ where $\varphi\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R^2})$ is exactly 1. I have already shown that it is less than or equal to 1 but I haven't been able to show that it can't be 0. I am allowed to use the fact that the distribution $$\langle T',\varphi\rangle=\int_0^{+\infty}(\varphi(x)-\varphi(0))\frac{dx}{x^k}$$ has order 1 whenever $1<k<2$.

Could somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Do you mean $\varphi \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$? It seems to take two arguments.

Comment: @md2perpe yes, thanks for the remark

Answer (score 1):

Using the variable substitution $t=1/s$ we get
$$
\langle T,\varphi\rangle
%= \int_\mathbb{R}(\varphi(t^{-2},\sin t)-\varphi(0,\sin t)) \, dt
%= \left(\int_{-\infty}^0 + \int_0^\infty \right) (\varphi(t^{-2},\sin t)-\varphi(0,\sin t)) \, dt
%= \{ s:=1/t \}
%= \left(\int_{-\infty}^{0} + \int_0^{\infty} \right) (\varphi(s^2,\sin \frac{1}{s})-\varphi(\infty,\sin \frac{1}{s})) \, \frac{ds}{s^2}
= \int_{\mathbb{R}}  \left( \varphi(s^2,\sin \frac{1}{s}) - \varphi(0,\sin \frac{1}{s}) \right) \, \frac{ds}{s^2}
$$

Now,
$$
\varphi(s^2,\sin \frac{1}{s})
= \varphi(0,\sin \frac{1}{s}) + s^2 \varphi'_1(0,\sin \frac{1}{s}) + s^4 o(s)
$$
so close to $s=0$ the integrand is $\varphi'_1(0,\sin \frac{1}{s})$ suggesting that $T$ has order 1.

Perhaps you can make this more precise?

Comment: I need to prove it in a more formal way. I have already shown that the order is $\leq 1$ but I need to show that indeed it is not 0. Maybe taking a sequence of test functions to show that I can’t bound $|\langle T, \varphi\rangle|$ by the infinite norm of $\varphi$ could work, but I haven’t been able to find the appropriate test functions

Comment: @GRJ. Try to find a sequence $\varphi_k$ of test functions with $\sup |\varphi_k| \to 0$ but $\partial_x \varphi_k(x=0,y) = 1$ and show that $\langle T, \varphi_k \rangle \not\to 0.$